# Windows Authentication .Net Core 2.0 Show Username Without Security Prompt

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a brand new Asp.Net Core 2.0 web mvc application with windows authentication enabled. 
If I immediately hit play it prompts me for user credentials which is not what I want. If I hit cancel it then redirects me to a 401.2 unauthorized error screen with the following error:

> "You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid
>   authentication headers."

When I then stop the application and enable anonymous authentication on the project and hit play again, it runs the application successfully but will not display my username. `@User.Identity.Name` returns empty string.

How do I get around the security prompt while still being able to display my username?

In the .NET Framework, I would use this in the web.config file along with anonymous authentication = true and it would work the way I want:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I am using Visual Studio 15.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `<authentication>` tag is related to ASP.NET, and not IIS. In ASP.NET Core, the *System.Web* pipeline doesn't run.

I've had success in implementing Windows authentication with ASP.NET Core by using the following configuration in the `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `<system.webServer>` section is the one getting modified when you change the authentication settings through IIS Manager.

---

*Edit after Ben's first comment*

Sorry, I had misread part of your initial message, and thought that you were trying to deploy your application in IIS.

It looks like Windows Authentication is set up correctly since you get prompted for credentials. What I don't understand is why you get prompted. I'm using IE11, Edge and Chrome, and they all know how to send Windows credentials without prompting me.

What browser are you using when doing your test? Could you try with the ones I listed above?

Comment: I have tried adding a web.config to my project and adding the code you suggested but it does not work. It actually errors out on the windows authentication line (500.19 The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.)

Comment: Still no luck on this one. I am testing on IE11 and Edge. It only prompts me on initial load of the app but can then browse through the app after inputting my credentials that first time. If I ever find the answer I will update this post. Thanks.